# an illegal memory access was encountered

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I am a beginner at CUDA programming, writing a program composed of a single file `main.cu` which is shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#define DEBUG(str) std::cerr << "\033[1;37m" << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ": \033[1;31merror:\033[0m " << str << std::endl;

#define CUDADEBUG(cudaError)      \
    if (cudaError != cudaSuccess) \
        DEBUG(cudaGetErrorString(cudaError));

#define ERROR(str)  \
    {               \
        DEBUG(str); \
        exit(1);    \
    }

__global__ void makeGrey(
    unsigned char *&pimage,
    const int &cn,
    const size_t &total)
{
    unsigned i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned icn = i * cn;

    printf("%u\n", i);

    if (i < total)
    {
        float result = pimage[icn + 0] * .114 +
                       pimage[icn + 1] * .587 +
                       pimage[icn + 2] * .299;
        pimage[icn + 0] = result; //B
        pimage[icn + 1] = result; //G
        pimage[icn + 2] = result; //R
        // pimage[icn + 3] *= result; //A
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
        ERROR("usage: executable in out");

    cv::Mat image;
    unsigned char *dimage;

    image = cv::imread(argv[1], cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    if (!image.data)
        ERROR("Image null");

    if (image.empty())
        ERROR("Image empty");

    if (!image.isContinuous())
        ERROR("image is not continuous");

    const size_t N = image.total();
    const int cn = image.channels();
    const size_t numOfElems = cn * N;
    const int blockSize = 512;
    const int gridSize = (N - 1) / blockSize + 1;

    CUDADEBUG(cudaMalloc(&dimage, numOfElems * sizeof(unsigned char)));
    CUDADEBUG(cudaMemcpy(dimage, image.data, numOfElems * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    makeGrey<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(dimage, cn, N);
    cudaError_t errSync = cudaGetLastError();
    cudaError_t errAsync = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (errSync != cudaSuccess)
        std::cerr << "Sync kernel error: " << cudaGetErrorString(errSync) << std::endl;
    if (errAsync != cudaSuccess)
        std::cerr << "Async kernel error: " << cudaGetErrorString(errAsync) << std::endl;

    CUDADEBUG(cudaMemcpy(image.data, dimage, numOfElems * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)); //line 73
    CUDADEBUG(cudaFree(dimage));                                                                           //line 74

    cv::imwrite(argv[2], image);
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the program, I get

```
Async kernel error: an illegal memory access was encountered
/path-to-main.cu:73: error: an illegal memory access was encountered
/path-to-main.cu:74: error: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

I checked `CV_VERSION` macro which is `4.5.3-dev`, and Cuda Toolkit 11.4 is installed (`nvcc` version 11.4). Also afaik, the kernel does not execute at all (I used Nsight gdb debugger and printf). I could not understand why I am accessing an illegal memory area. I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your GPU function `makeGrey` takes it's arguments by reference, those values live on the stack, not in GPU-memory, take them by value instead.

Comment: Thank you @Kaldrr. Do you know any advice or tutorial on how to debug cuda applications? Do I have to check millions of threads by hand? Secondly, I am sorry I didn't know the fact that I shouldn't use references. I thought `cudaMalloc` supports references. Why is that? And lastly, what should I do to increase your reputation? If you write an answer, I will accept or whatever it takes to make it.

Comment: An online tutorial on CUDA debugging is available [here](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/).

Comment: @Kaldrr I accepted your answer. In your post, you tell the parameter values reside in memory, but I used `cudaMalloc`. Does not it count as allocating a piece of memory in GPU (VRAM etc) instead of the main memory? I thought the plain c++ style of references would work there too, as we do for the main memory.

Comment: @HakanDemir The way you use `cudaMalloc` has nothing to do with the way arguments are passed to your `makeGrey` function. Whenever you references as function arguments in C++, you're telling the compiler that you're not passing the value directly, but rather a place in memory where such value exists. But this value exists in Host/CPU memory, which means Device/GPU code will try to read value using a reference, which points to a value in Host/CPU memory, which is very much undefined behavior (most likely a crash) in your case.

Comment: @Kaldrr So as I understood, `cudaMalloc` does not directly allocate memory in GPU, but just points to the location of variables in main memory to be later passed to the GPU memory. Therefore, the variables still reside in main memory. Thank you.

Comment: @HakanDemir I added an image to my answer to better illustrate what I ment, `cudaMalloc` does allocate memory on the GPU, but you save the pointer that keeps that memory address in Host memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, your GPU function takes arguments by references.

```cpp
__global__ void makeGrey(
    unsigned char *&pimage,
    const int &cn,
    const size_t &total)
```

This is bad, passing a reference to a function means more or less that you're passing an address where you can find the value, not the value itself.
In your situation those values are in memory used by Host, **NOT** Device/GPU memory, when GPU tries to access those values it will most likely crash.

The types you are trying to pass, `unsigned char*`, `int` and `size_t` are very cheap to copy, there's no need to pass them by reference in the 1st place.

```cpp
__global__ void makeGrey(
    unsigned char *pimage,
    const int cn,
    const size_t total)
```

There are tools provided by nvidia to debug CUDA applications, but I'm not really familiar with them, you can also use `printf` inside GPU functions, but you will have to organize output from potentially thousand of threads.

In general, whenever you call GPU functions, be very cautious about what you're passing as parameters, as they need to be passed from Host memory to Device memory. Usually you want to pass everything by value, any pointers need to point to Device memory, and watch out from references.

[image]